# Let $n$ be a natural number. (a) Write the contrapositive of the statement "If 2 is a factor of $n^2$ then $2$ is a factor of $n$". (b) Prove the cont

Tags: logic

Let $n$ be a natural number.

(a) Write the contrapositive of the statement "If $2$ is a factor of $n^2$ then $2$ is a factor of $n$".

Contrapositive: If 2 is not a factor of $n$, then $2$ is not a factor of $n^2$.

(b) Prove the contrapositive of the statement (a).

I'm stuck here. I have done before math induction to prove a number is a factor of a polynomial but not that is not a factor neither have done a proof of a conditional with math induction.

Help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proof beginning: Suppose that $2$ is not a factor of $n$. Then this implies that $n$ is odd.

Hint: What is the square of an odd number?

Full Proof:

> Suppose that $2$ is not a factor of $n$. This implies that $n$ is odd. Because an odd number multiplied by an odd number is always odd, we have that $n^2$ is odd and thus not a multiple of $2$. Or in other words, $2$ is not a factor of $n^2$.

Comment: Hey @Seeker! Thanks for the hint. So if $2$ is not a factor of $n$ then it is odd: $n=2k+1$. Then $n^2=(2k+1)^2=2k^2+4k+1=(2k^2+4k)+1=2(k^2+2k)+1$. So $n^2$ is odd as well, therefore $2$ is not a factor. Is this ok?

Comment: @bdvg2302 Yeah that's correct!

Comment: thank u for bringing light :-)

Comment: @bdvg2302 You're welcome!